# GitHub - Commit specific files from one repo to another

Tags: git, github

I have 2 repos:

1. Engine Scripting repo
2. Scripting Documentation repo

I'm using [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/) to generate all the documentation when I update the C# scripting project (located in Engine Scripting repo).

DocFX creates a folder _site everytime I compile the project and what I need to do is to push all the content inside _site folder to Scripting Documentation repo automatically (not copying the files manually to the other repo), without having the Documentation repo locally in my drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- clone Scripting Documentation repo anywhere you want
- use the _site folder generated by your update as a working tree for the cloned repo

That is, whenever you launch a command/script updating your site, add the command:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/_site --git-dir=/path/to/cloned/Scripting/Doc/.git add .
git --work-tree=/path/to/_site --git-dir=/path/to/cloned/Scripting/Doc/.git commit -m "Update Scripting Doc"
git --work-tree=/path/to/_site --git-dir=/path/to/cloned/Scripting/Doc/.git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can finish these automatically in continuous integration tools. Here is what DocFX's sample project [docfx-seed](https://github.com/docascode/docfx-seed) do, using [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) CI service:

https://github.com/docascode/docfx-seed/blob/master/appveyor.yml